# XCode 9.1 Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

Tags: objective-c, xcode9

After updating xcode to version 9.1, I can't compile my projects, always have the same error Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1. I tried to create empty project, install all pods I need, and the result is the same. Here is my podfile

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'xcode9.1' do

pod 'RMStore'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'RMMapper'
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'FacebookShare'
pod 'VK-ios-sdk'
pod 'TwitterKit'
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurrySDK'
pod 'TWSReleaseNotesView'
pod 'GoogleAnalytics'
pod 'GoogleTagManager','~> 3.15.0'
pod 'SBJson'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'APOfflineReverseGeocoding'
pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'Realm'

end
```

This problem repeats in all my projects, can anybody explain me how to fix it?

Here is the screen of full error
[image]

Comment: pls post the complete error msg

Comment: updated with error

Comment: Have you tried deleting your DerivedData folder before you compile? This folder isn't reusable between versions of XCode.

Comment: yes, I deleted DerivedData, update all profiles, removed workspace, reinstall pods, readded schemas, nothing helps

Comment: Also tried to delete DervidedData -> did not help. Also tried to refresh the provisioningProfiles -> did not help. Would be nice if someone can help!

Comment: I have the same troubles with Xcode 9.1. This error suddenly appeared while working with my current project.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very simple. In your pods target, Build settings, I changed valid architectures list. Also Build architectures only flag change to No can resolve the problem.

[image]